# DB Browser for Sqlite New Record GUI

Tags: sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

Sometimes when I click the "new record" button in DB Browser for Sqlite, a new row is added with cells which I can click into and fill. Other times it creates a pop up window where I can enter my data, as in the picture below. There seems to be no pattern to which one of these happens. I want to enter data into the cells because it is much more convenient. Does anyone know how to force this entry mode please?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dialog opens when there is a constraint that you have to fulfilled in order to insert the new values. DB Browser tries to open a new row inline adding new default values, and when it cannot accomplish the constraints, opens this dialog for you so you can insert the values taking into account the constraints. You can see the constraints in tooltips shown for each row.

You can see the rationale behind this dialog here: https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/pull/1477